# Text not changing with CSS class for CurrentPage

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navigation bar. I have made a class for the active page which is "Current". The color on the button text normally is the background color, but when active i want it to change to white. It is not doing this though it is only changing the background color which blends in with the text. I was wondering if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you! :)

```
<a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
```

CSS:

```css
.current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #b23758;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav > li > a {
display: block; 
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0;
color:#b23758;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: tried `white` not `white.`?

Comment: yep sorry about that, still not working as just white;

Comment: works fine. What is the output you are getting? post a screenshot and even better a jsfiddle. You sure there is no other style overriding the color or background?

Comment: Will something like this ok? http://jsfiddle.net/9yqwkqw8/

Comment: i'm pretty sure that some styles in other selectors overriding your **.current** style. Just look into web developers tools in Chrome or Firefox. Also, you can test this by adding **!important** after **white**, but better don't use this in your final css. You can override style just adding more complex type of selector, eg **.current.current**, or **#parentid .current**

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote is correct and something else on your page must be overwriting the style.

In your code `.nav > li > a` has a greater specificity than `.current`

So in order for `.current` to overwrite the `a` tag you can write:

`a.current` to increase it's specificity.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
a.current {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b23758;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove (.) from `color: white.;`

try this:

```
.current a:active {
color: white;
background-color: #b23758;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
color: white !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav > li > a.current {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `!important`

Instead, find the style overwriting your class `.current`. Your selector targeting `.current` most likely needs to be more specific in order to overwrite the other style.

Try this:

```
.nav > li > a.current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #b23758;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine and u can check here i created running snippet for this code .

```js
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

```css
.current {
  color: white;
  background-color: #b23758;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #b23758;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
<a href="#">Home2</a>
<a href="#">Home3</a>
<a href="#">Home4</a>
<a href="#">Home5</a>
<a href="#">Home6</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this small Example.

It will help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:active {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white !important;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
</body>

</html>
```